# ActiveRecord Connection Pool checkout_timeout not being used

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, connection-pooling

I'm setting the checkout_timeout for ActiveRecord:

```
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    adapter: 'postgresql',
    database: 'abe',
    host: 'redacted',
    username: 'redacted',
    password: '',
    checkout_timeout: 15,
  )

#...
ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
  #...
end
```

But:

```
connection_pool.rb:190:in `block in wait_poll': could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.001 seconds) (ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError)
```

Any ideas?